# What about self-construction in C++: should copy and move constructors handle calls with `*this` correctly?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

What are best practices in C++ when the copy/move constructors are called with the object itself?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo{
    Foo( const Foo& foo ) { cout << foo.val << std::endl; };
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f = Foo(f);
    Foo g(g);
    Foo h{h};
    return 0;
}
```

This is all legal C++, though some compilers will warn you about it.

It is commonly advised that [copy assignment operators check for self-assignment](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/assignment-operators). But what about self-copy construction?

Comment: I cannot think of any time that it would be valid to copy to yourself during constructor. `Foo f = Foo(f);` invokes undefined behaviour, so it's meaningless anyway.

Comment: self assignment is more likely to happen accidentally. Say you have two references `a` and `b` and call `a = b;` then typically you wouldnt check whether `a == b` before. On the other hand `Foo g(g);` isnt happening that easily without being noticed

Comment: moreover the rationale they outline here https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/assignment-operators#self-assignment-why doesnt apply to constructors. I mean there is a reason that `Foo h{h};` is wrong, but its a different one

Comment: I am not sure how this can be answered. Asking for "best practice" is border line opinion based. The FAQ you link doesnt mention it anywhere and neither does the core guidelines afaik. Would that count as an answer?

Comment: "This is all legal C++" It isnt. You dont initialize `val`

Comment: Don't see how you can think this is anything extra a constraint violation.  Caller has to pass a valid object for the parameter, and a reference to the object-under-construction is certainly not valid.  If there was a prior object at that location, its lifetime has already ended, and the object which will be there has not yet started its lifetime.

Comment: imho Ben Voigts comment nails it. `Foo g(g)` fails to met a precondition. If a functions preconditions is not met its not the functions responsibility to recover. There is no precondition for assignment that would state that you shall not `a = a`. Because it is allowed, `operator=` should handle it. Long story short, the core guidelines has a section on preconditions and talks about best practices on how to express them https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i5-state-preconditions-if-any

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor for `T` creates a new object whose value is the same as that of an existing object (the argument for the copy constructor). If you pass the object to its own copy constructor, it doesn't *have* a value yet, so there's no value to copy.

This can therefore be viewed as calling the copy constructor "out of contract", a bit like if the argument to the copy constructor were an object that had already been destroyed. It's not a valid call, so you don't need to check for this case in the implementation—unlike the situation with a self-copy-assignment, where `x = x;` is a valid call, so you do need to make sure it works properly.

If it were common for users to accidentally pass an object to its own constructor, there might perhaps be value in having a purely defensive check in the implementation, but code like `Foo g(g);` is highly unlikely to be written.

It is even less likely that someone will attempt to move-construct an object from itself.